# Preventing override of individual methods in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

I know that I can use the sealed in order to prevent other classes to inherit a certain class,
but is it possible to allow inheritance but prevent overriding of some virtual methods?

Answer (score 50):

Only `virtual` methods can be overridden.
Just leave out `virtual`, and your method will not be overridable.

Comment: This works for public methods but not for private ones.

Answer (score 47):

you can also use sealed modifier to prevent a derived class from further overriding the method.

check this out: [Sealed methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645769(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Wrong.  The `sealed` keyword can only be used on an overridden method to prevent further overrides; that's not what he's asking for.

Comment: Hmm, the question doesn't make any sense unless the OP is talking about a virtual method.  Let's try to give sensible answers to sensible questions.  This answer is sensible.

Comment: SLaks: the sealed modifier is perfectly acceptable. It's just a matter of structuring the inheritance...

Answer (score 18):

Yes. The `sealed` keyword can also be used on methods, to indicate that a method which is virtual or abstract at higher inheritance levels cannot be further inherited.

If the method was never virtual or abstract to begin with, no worries; it can't be overridden.

Note that `sealed` only affects method overriding; method *hiding* cannot be stopped in this way, so a child class can still declare a `new` method of the same name and signature as your sealed method.

Answer (score 11):

You can get the `sealed` keyword to work on a method in the abstract class by making that abstract class itself derived from something:

```
abstract class DocumentTemplateBase
{
    public abstract void WriteTitle();
    public abstract void WriteSections();
}

abstract class DocumentTemplate : DocumentTemplateBase
{
    public override sealed void WriteTitle() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Project document"); 
    }

    public override sealed void WriteSections() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sections");
    }

    abstract public void WriteContent();
}
```

Still deriving your concrete class from the original (and now derived) abstract class:

```
class Document1_FromTemplate : DocumentTemplate
{
    public override void WriteTitle() //error!
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Project1 document");
    }
```

> "cannot override inherited member 'Dynamics.DocumentTemplate.WriteTitle()' because it is sealed"

There is nothing, however to prevent an implementer from `new`ing it:

```
class Document1_FromTemplate : DocumentTemplate
{
    public new void WriteTitle() //sorry! can't stop it!
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Project1 document");
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `sealed` keyword in two ways:

1. Before a class to avoid inheritance.
2. Before a function to avoid overriding.

To allow inheritance don’t put the `sealed` keyword before the class and to avoid overriding put `sealed` before the function which you don’t want to be overridden.

Comment: nice answer. Consider using formatting for numbered list and such. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2):

Yes. you need to use **sealed override** for the method  to achieve it.