# Prevent/Generate warning if subclass calls an overriden member

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

Given the following pseudo C# code:

```
public abstract class Worker
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
         Prepare();
         Work();
         Cleanup();
    }

    protected abstract void Work();
}
```

With this design, it is possible, that a derived class (which overrides the `Work()` method) calls the `Work()` method directly.

I'm looking for design tips on how to prevent any subclass to do this call, or at least generate a compiler warning.

Why I want to do this?
The Worker actually dispatches the `Work()` to another thread. `DoWork()` takes care about the locking.

---

I know, this is weird. The `Work()`-body might just consist of a method call to `DoMyWork()` and the object might call `DoMyWork()` somewhere else. It's impossible to intercept that.

Anyways. I appreciate any thoughts on that issue.

Comment: Is it help? [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274639/preventing-override-of-individual-methods-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You know that (your use case aside) it sounds kind of schizophrenic to forbid an object to run a method it itself implements (in the case of an abstract class it kind of does not override but implement a method). I will think some time about the use case but I'm quite sure there is no way to achieve it that way.

Comment: Have you considered making `Work` an event instead?

Comment: @Eris Nothing to stop the derived class from invoking the event directly... unless the event itself is private and only has a set accessor property perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Eris and Corey I think I figured it out. What about this way:

```
public abstract class Worker
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
         if (Work != null)
         {
             Prepare();
             Work();
             Cleanup();
         }
    }

    protected Action Work { private get; set; }
}

public class ImplWorker {
    public ImplWorker() {
        Work = //whatever
    }
}
```

Still if he really wanted to he can store it somewhere else and stuff. But it goes as far as I can imagine.

Comment: This would break any class which previously inherited from Worker. If you're going to do that, then you may as well just go ahead and completely remove the method.

Comment: If you want to forbid something that was possible before it will always end up in breaking changes or do I misunderstand the purpose?

Comment: I think this is quite what I consider "enough effort made to prevent using it the wrong way". Thanks!

Comment: You're weclome. I can not imagine any way even more protected and I think this code alone sends a strong message to any programmer how he is supposed to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If the Work is done using a resource (e.g. remote server, database connection), or it can be changed to be like that, then you could do it like this:

```
public interface IResource
{
}

public abstract class Worker
{
    private class TheResource : IResource
    {
        // implement
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        Prepare();

        var resObj = new TheResource();
        Work(resObj);
        // if needed, cleanup/dispose resObj here

        Cleanup();
    }

    protected abstract void Work(IResource resourceObj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat of a hack, but you could change the method to be virtual, add a body which calls the new method, and then add an [ObsoleteAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22kk2b44(v=vs.90).aspx) to it.

```
    protected void DoWork()
    {
        // New method
    }

    [Obsolete("This method is deprecated.")]
    protected virtual void Work()
    {
        DoWork();
    }
```

Marking the method as virtual will prevent any existing child classes from breaking, since they were previously required to override Work().